# Bulk edit DataStage jobs?

Tags: etl, database-migration, datastage, ibm-infosphere

We are repointing a large number (>1000) DataStage jobs from one database to another. As part of this, we will need to make the same changes to a single stage for many jobs.

So far, we have been able to export jobs to XML, edit and reimport. This seems to work, but will require a lot of parsing logic. We also have looked at `dsjob`, but that tool does not seem to have the ability to edit jobs.

What is the best method (UI or CLI/API) to bulk edit job stages?

Answer (score 2):

Scenarios like this are the reason for using parameters for Databases - I recommend using ParameterSets with DBName, User, Password and Schema parameters.

This allows an easy and quick change in one place of a project: the ParameterSet

Hard coding all these things will give you a hard time - the export method is one option you know already.

There is a connector migration wizard - I am not sure if this tool could be helpful as well - you might want to search for documentation on that.

Comment: Thanks! We are using parameters sets in some places, but there are many legacy jobs where params are not in use. 

Will check out the connector migration wizard.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try the RJUT (Rapid Job Update Tool) or the CMT (Connector Migration Tool).

RJUT: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/rapid-job-update-tool-ibm-infosphere-information-server-datastage-jobs

CMT:  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=connectors-using-command-line-migrate-jobs